# Python dictionary details

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable, language-features

I would like to know where the source code for python's Dictionary is located. I know the source code will probably difficult to read so I'm really just after a rough description of the implementation and the hash routine which is used.

Does anybody know what sort of algorithm is used and how they deal with collisions, if chaining is used or is the table rebuilt.

I know this question is a bit vague so just a point in the right direction would be helpful please. If anybody know of any good documentation on python's dictionary that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's located in the [`Objects/dictobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c) file. There is a [`dictnotes.txt` file](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab4b8da79a5f/Objects/dictnotes.txt) there too, to guide you in understanding the source.

Python dictionaries use a hashtable with open addressing to map keys to slots. Conflicts are resolved by 'perturbing' the key; an algorithm that'll start with a large step, then use smaller and smaller steps until it scans the table for the next empty slot.

There are several articles on the web, including [this blog post](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/); you can also pick up the book Beautiful Code for an excellent exposure of the code.

Comment: +1 for the speed of answering!! just 33 seconds after question has been posted :)

Answer (score 2):

The source tree has quite good docs on how dictionaries work:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab4b8da79a5f/Objects/dictnotes.txt

Answer (score 2):

also.. . here is a active state recipe of `dict` which is more efficiant(`from 3 to 24 times more space efficient than regular dictionaries`)!! .otherwise previous two answers are great!! 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578375-proof-of-concept-for-a-more-space-efficient-faster/?in=user-178123

Comment: Have you tested that implementation against the built-in dict (in different scenarious)?

Comment: yes... i have tested them for default size,; its 1/4th of python's built-in dicts..

Comment: NB it's from a core developer (Raymond Hettinger) and was considered (don't think any conclusive results came from it) for inclusion in `dictobject.c`. The Python implementation is *not* better than the C implementation in most cases. In any case, this is not an answer.

Comment: @delnan: yes this is not an answer.. but at-least  it will give an idea about dict and it is working to the OP in a readable python format!! that's why i wrote in my post that; previous two answers are great!!!

Comment: @PeterRowell: does the pure(or achievable) cython version of this recipe can add some more improvement in it?? (because its just 175 lines.. .i have not tried the cythonized version; just asking opinion about it)

Comment: @namit: Raymond's approach should work in any implementation language. I don't know how well it deals with the many different use cases for dicts, but small dicts would almost certainly be quite fast using this approach. The proof is in the benchmarks! :-)